# LetsEncryptCerfifcates Fail in Docker Compose Wordpress

Tags: ubuntu, docker-compose, lets-encrypt

I'm following [How To Install WordPress With Docker Compose](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-wordpress-with-docker-compose#step-6-completing-the-installation-through-the-web-interface) to spin up a Wordpress website in docker-compose on a fresh Ubuntu Sever install. I'm stuck on step 4 as I cannot get letsencrypt to work properly. I have my ports open. I disabled the firewall and that still didn't work.  I'm using AT&T if that matters. I've followed the tutorial exactly as laid out. Others have used it successfully.

Any ideas?

**Logs**

```
certbot     certbot certonly --webroot ...   Exit 1                                   
db          docker-entrypoint.sh --def ...   Up       3306/tcp, 33060/tcp             
webserver   nginx -g daemon off;             Up       0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp,:::80->80/tcp
wordpress   docker-entrypoint.sh php-fpm     Up       9000/tcp                        
cyadmin@cyserver:/wordpress$ docker-compose logs -f -t
Attaching to certbot, webserver, wordpress, db
wordpress    | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.441456682Z [30-Dec-2023 06:50:11] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 1
wordpress    | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.442062665Z [30-Dec-2023 06:50:11] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:10.946113501Z 2023-12-30 06:50:10+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.234775735Z 2023-12-30 06:50:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.252234575Z 2023-12-30 06:50:11+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.35-1.el8 started.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.466284543Z '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' -> '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.727305887Z 2023-12-30T06:50:11.721816Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011068] [Server] The syntax '--skip-host-cache' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use SET GLOBAL host_cache_size=0 instead.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.727340201Z 2023-12-30T06:50:11.723298Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010918] [Server] 'default_authentication_plugin' is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. Please use authentication_policy instead.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.727348641Z 2023-12-30T06:50:11.723332Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.35) starting as process 1
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:11.734094695Z 2023-12-30T06:50:11.733758Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.176207979Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.176088Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.579171254Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.575754Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.579209803Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.575797Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.580982935Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.580855Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.619257377Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.619134Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Bind-address: '::' port: 33060, socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
db           | 2023-12-30T06:50:12.619405544Z 2023-12-30T06:50:12.619211Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.35'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:13.215280850Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:13.494216603Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279875353Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279906051Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279911822Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279916288Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279920210Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/fZFo24fAX-XQE39OUE9pKcLlW5xZbCfr4haZrHaOWWQ: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279926438Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279932571Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279937840Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279941751Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/_S8Tn-O5NWC7fWR9PE9Uo4MN7cO0ghVO7QwwnQE5oOE: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279946108Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279949848Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.279954825Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.284012306Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:50:24.284087101Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:17.198157319Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:17.426749304Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240715098Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240745521Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240753159Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240758926Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240764836Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/VrNxBKfsFGWbd-UwletZkuSJqGsyPk8SSh8pm-itkro: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240771788Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240777325Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240783000Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240788784Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/p5VVettJqQkToLOW6gVX92KAghwtlZ2dzbIRAKTMF4I: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240794991Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240800261Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.240820937Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.246037032Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:52:28.246113139Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:18.907936323Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:19.182640480Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996944280Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996973541Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996978918Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996982971Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996987386Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/PGXIvLAhrT0OvgjFpw1bZOkAOSTQ4trWcSLLwid0I4g: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.996994590Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997000652Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997004929Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997008771Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/O4jdkyQXVB-XvN4I5SShtCVKdk0YqWmg9Ijq9s7VIJ8: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997081399Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997088674Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:29.997093561Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:30.003314223Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:30.003386467Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:31.758009317Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:31.972302420Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807735549Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807763834Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807773125Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807779948Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807786102Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/TBfRjPWUBPEasfFVGwM0zsbsvshK-0FGF84jRx9mQAY: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807792864Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807799355Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807807188Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807824357Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/4Un5qwpUrXWS5mga88hcUWanBIA0c0wUKeUzqG6BtFY: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807832121Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807838752Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.807845568Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.812762507Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:53:42.812822323Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:40.798421187Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:41.032449466Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861265413Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861302160Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861308555Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861315021Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861320878Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/9zlvfmWTKSBei0mQ3zpEQVyibAPmzdR-wI0mN6Oq2qQ: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861325509Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861329570Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861333354Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861337045Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/EC3QZ4-kVCn94wcRTiaSlCOHo7kEgjfSHHCBrvptKzw: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861342224Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861345899Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.861350278Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.870275325Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:57:51.870384697Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:41.083747844Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:41.294788760Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.065963475Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.065986291Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.065994328Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066011759Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066016520Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/TQ-TIZN7m9nl5FXFERtnWnBKyxiCDWycp-Q_zv24NpE: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066021015Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066024836Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066028892Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066032657Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/krre7cWbRfyS0VQ3lwLciLyJQD8PVq-MFN33EPNC0vw: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066046746Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066050760Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.066055297Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.068547258Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T06:58:52.068611003Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:23.561683914Z Saving debug log to /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:23.771720734Z Requesting a certificate for crowdsourcedtribune.org and www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558557025Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558581420Z Certbot failed to authenticate some domains (authenticator: webroot). The Certificate Authority reported these problems:
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558587920Z   Domain: crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558594694Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558600168Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/RdHbT3SvL_dEubXGmd8xhP-csuLcg1U5-gv1FYVWIro: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558604538Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558608205Z   Domain: www.crowdsourcedtribune.org
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558611935Z   Type:   connection
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558615632Z   Detail: 76.201.20.193: Fetching http://www.crowdsourcedtribune.org/.well-known/acme-challenge/rWQ_XMa4NBzypbLfASz1SRJRYd41URy3FAovqoOwjN0: Timeout during connect (likely firewall problem)
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558620899Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558624599Z Hint: The Certificate Authority failed to download the temporary challenge files created by Certbot. Ensure that the listed domains serve their content from the provided --webroot-path/-w and that files created there can be downloaded from the internet.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.558629119Z 
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.560976305Z Some challenges have failed.
certbot      | 2023-12-30T07:01:34.561035121Z Ask for help or search for solutions at https://community.letsencrypt.org. See the logfile /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log or re-run Certbot with -v for more details.
certbot exited with code 1
```

Comment: First of all make sure, that the domains resolve to the correct IP addresse. Second, the http challenge tries to connect via port 80. Is there any process listening on that port? As you mention docker-compose: Is the port of the container bound to the the correct port in the host? Can you access that webserver with a browser? Is your server located at some hosting provider or is it located at home? If the latter, does your internet provider allow inbound traffic on the required ports?

Comment: The ports aren't being used by  to anything else. The machine is in my house on the same network. I believe my isp allows this because I had a similar set up with apache and cloudflare and moved to this tutorial for easier tranferability and backup. The docker successfully pings other sites.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind! This was a me issue completely. I didn't have port forwarding properly configured on my router